# Polynomials and holomorphicity

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

I have P, a holomorphic polynomial with no zeros.
How can I show that P can be written as $$P(z) = P(0) + zQ(z)?$$

This seems simple, but I don't think I understand how to solve it.

Any help would be great.

Comment: No zeros in what domain? Unless $P$ is constant, it will have zeros in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Also, what's the point of saying $P$ is holomorphic? Aren't all polynomials holomorphic?

Comment: The domain was not mentioned

Comment: Finally, the equation $P(z) = P(0) + zQ(z)$ is automatic. Write $P(z)$ as a sum of monomials. Then compute $P(0)$. It's just the constant term, right? Then note that the other terms are all multiples of $z$, so if you factor the sum of those terms, you get $zQ(z)$.